# Error after converting to Swift 3 ( AnyObject is not a subtype of UIFontDescriptor )

Tags: ios, swift3, anyobject

after converting my swift code to swift 3. I got the following mistake:

( AnyObject is not a subtype of UIFontDescriptor ) in my code

```
 public init(controller : UIViewController) {
    super.init()

    addResponderFromView(controller.view)
}

deinit {

    for infoDict in textFieldInfoCache {

        let view : AnyObject = (infoDict as AnyObject).object(forKey: kIQTextField)!

        if let textField = view as? UITextField {

            let returnKeyTypeValue = infoDict[kIQTextFieldReturnKeyType] as! NSNumber
            textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType(rawValue: returnKeyTypeValue.intValue)!

            textField.delegate = infoDict[kIQTextFieldDelegate] as! UITextFieldDelegate?
        } else if let textView = view as? UITextView {

            textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType(rawValue: (infoDict[kIQTextFieldReturnKeyType] as! NSNumber).intValue)!

            let returnKeyTypeValue = infoDict[kIQTextFieldReturnKeyType] as! NSNumber
            textView.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType(rawValue: returnKeyTypeValue.intValue)!

            textView.delegate = infoDict[kIQTextFieldDelegate] as! UITextViewDelegate?
        }
    }

    textFieldInfoCache.removeAllObjects()
}
```

please take a look at the picture. Any ideas how to fix that?[image]

Comment: Why do you keep casting your `infoDict` to an `AnyObject`? And, for that matter, why use `object(forKey:)` instead of just `["key"]`?

Comment: What type is your `infoDict`?

Comment: `AnyObject` is always very bad in Swift 3. Care about the real types

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in Swift 3, `UIFontDescriptor` is a struct.

A struct is a value type, not an object type. (`Any`, not `AnyObject`.) Try casting it to `Any` instead of `AnyObject`.

Comment: If you mean like that:  let view : Any = (infoDict as AnyObject).object(forKey: kIQTextField)!
It works but the remaining part is still in red :(